# Xcode build but launch app with black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a problem with my xcode, all worked before but suddenly my app does not launch.

Xcode saying that it's launching but I just have black screen on simulator and nothing in the log...

I try on device but It's the same problem.

**Screen of xcode :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYh4y.png

***Edit : I tried with an other project and the app it's running.***

***Edit 2 : The problem come from storyboard... I will post a new ask. Thanks***

Comment: Can't really diagnose the problem with a picture.... Tell us more

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, some code would help.

Comment: Make sure your initial view controller is set

Comment: But I didn't change the code when problem appended so I don't know what I can give you ...

Comment: @box86rowh Yes, is set

Comment: both in the project settings and on the storyboard?

Comment: @box86rowh Yes, but how I said I didn't change anything before the problem appended

Comment: how about run it on device? simulator sometimes just **very very** slow on loading

Comment: It is the same thing, the app don't launch and I just have the launch screen

Comment: If you haven't changed any code and this is happening you could try cleaning the build. Product - Clean or Shift+Cmd+K (I think, not on a mac right now). This has helped me out a few times!

Comment: I already try to clean but it´s not work

Comment: I edit ask : I tried with an other project and the app is running.

Comment: @Jopolaz You just delete all the apps from the simulator and try running the project, because having the same bundle identifier for two or more apps will create the issues like this.

Comment: @Jopolaz sometimes it takes a while for the app to start when you run it on the simulator the first time. Have you given it a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need this anymore, but I'm going to try to provide my answer for others out there.

*Sorry if I'm violating the rules, etc. I'm new here. :)*

Overall list of possible fixes (you guys have gotten here way before me, but I'll include them anyway--with credit).

- Sometimes, when it hasn't been used in a while (or if the project is new, etc.), the simulator takes a minute to load. **This was mentioned by 68cherries.**
- Did you check your storyboard entry point? I can't see it in the picture, but recently I've had it disappear a couple times. Just check "Is Initial View Controller"... see [this picture](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=kuj28&s=8).
- And finally... although this has been said by the great **Jim**... did you try "cleaning" your app? This always helps me out.

Anyway, I hope I haven't bothered you and that this helps anyone who may need it!